# Outgoing and Incoming Bandwidth at regular interval of time using Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

Is it possible to get stats like outgoing and incoming bandwidth used during a crawl using scrapy at regular interval of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. =)

The total request and response bytes are already tracked in the stats by the [DownloaderStats middleware that comes with Scrapy](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/downloadermiddleware/stats.py). You can add another [downloader middleware](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html) that tracks time and add the new stats.

Here are the steps for it:

1) Configure a new downloader middleware in `settings.py` with a high order number so it will execute later in the pipeline:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'testing.middlewares.InOutBandwithStats': 990,
}
```

2) Put the following code into a `middleware.py` file in the same dir as `settings.py`

```
import time


class InOutBandwithStats(object):

    def __init__(self, stats):
        self.stats = stats
        self.startedtime = time.time()

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler.stats)

    def elapsed_seconds(self):
        return time.time() - self.startedtime

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request_bytes = self.stats.get_value('downloader/request_bytes')

        if request_bytes:
            outgoing_bytes_per_second = request_bytes / self.elapsed_seconds()
            self.stats.set_value('downloader/outgoing_bytes_per_second',
                                 outgoing_bytes_per_second)

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        response_bytes = self.stats.get_value('downloader/response_bytes')

        if response_bytes:
            incoming_bytes_per_second = response_bytes / self.elapsed_seconds()
            self.stats.set_value('downloader/incoming_bytes_per_second',
                                 incoming_bytes_per_second)

        return response
```

And that's it. The process_request/process_response methods will be called whenever a request/response is processed and will keep updating the stats accordingly.

If you want to have logs at regular times you can also call `spider.log('Incoming bytes/sec: %s' % incoming_bytes_per_second)` there.

### Read more

- [Downloader middlewares in Scrapy - how to activate and create your own](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html)
- [DownloadStats - downloader middleware stats class](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/downloadermiddleware/stats.py)